# Use ldapjs with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ldapjs

I want to convert the following code to use promise. It is working and output a user's attributes within the active directory.

```
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: ldap_url
});

client.bind(ldap_username, ldap_password, function (err) {
    client.search(ldap_dn_search, opts, function (err, search) {
        search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
          var user = entry.object;
          // It is working!!!. It outputs all user attributes.
          console.log(user);
        });

    });
});
```

The following is my attempt, butit doesn't output anything.

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var client_bind = Promise.denodeify(client.bind);
var client_search = Promise.denodeify(client.search);

client_bind(ldap_username, ldap_password)
.then(function(err){
  client_search(ldap_dn_search, opts)
    .then(function(search){
      var search_on = Promise.denodeify(search.on);
      search_on('searchEntry')
        .then(function(entry){
          var user = entry.object;

          // It doesn't output anything !!!
          console.log(user);
        });
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. 
Search emits events, so we need something that processes them and passes further along the chain. 
Here is piece of code, that works for me:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var promise = require('bluebird');

var client = ldap.createClient({url: app.settings['ldap']['server']});
var uid;

promise.promisifyAll(client);

function searchPromise(res, notfoundtext) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var found = false;
    res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
      found = true;
      resolve(entry);
    });
    res.on('error', function(e) {
      reject(e.message);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      if (!found) {
        reject(notfoundtext);
      }
    });
  });
}

client.searchAsync(app.settings['ldap']['baseDn'], {filter: '(mail='+credentials.email+')', scope: 'sub'})
  .then(function(res) {
    return searchPromise(res, 'User isn\'t exists.');
  })
  .then(function (entry) {
    uid = entry.object.uid;
    return client.bindAsync(entry.object.dn, credentials.password);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return client.searchAsync('cn='+app.settings['ldap']['group']+',cn=groups,'+app.settings['ldap']['baseDn'], {scope: 'sub', filter: '(memberUid='+uid+')'});
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    return searchPromise(res, 'User is not in group ' + app.settings['ldap']['group']);
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('All is ok');
  })
  .catch(function(message) {
    console.log('Error:' + message);
  });
```

Immediately after the search I add one more step that catches the events, processes them, and passes it further along the chain. This makes the function searchPromise.

Good luck coding )

Answer (score 0):

Most likely those methods do require to be called on `client` as a context, so you will need to [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) them before passing them to `Promise.denodeify`:

```
var client_bind = Promise.denodeify(client.bind.bind(client));
var client_search = Promise.denodeify(client.search.bind(client));
```

Also, a proper use of promises would look like this:

```
client_bind(ldap_username, ldap_password).then(function() {
    return client_search(ldap_dn_search, opts);
//  ^^^^^^ always return something from the callback
}).then(function(search) { // flatten your chain
    return Promise.denodeify(search.on).call(search, 'searchEntry');
//                                    ^^^^^^ an alternative to `bind`
}).then(function(entry){
    var user = entry.object;
    console.log(user);
}).catch(function(err) { // always catch errors!
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I used the code you provided. I got error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE, even though I have process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0'; at the very top of my script.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a problem with the promises, is it?

Comment: I am not sure. If I switch it back to my original code, it is working with process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0'; If change the code to: "return Promise.denodeify(search.on).call(search, 'searchEntry');" to return 'something'; The exception stops.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bluebird Promises, the easy way to do this is to create your client normally, and then run the promisifyAll() on the client.

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://my-server:1234',
});

Promise.promisifyAll(client);
```

Now you can call client.addAsync() and client.searchAsync() and such.

```
client.bindAsync(secUserDn, secUserPassword)
  .then(doSearch) // if it works, call doSearch
  .catch(function (err) { // if bind fails, handle it
    console.error('Error on bind', err)
  });

function doSearch(data) {
  client.searchAsync('CN=A Test,OU=Users,DC=website,DC=com', options)
    .then(function (data) { // Handle the search result processing
      console.log('I got a result');
    })  
    .catch(function (err) { // Catch potential errors and handle them
      console.error('Error on search', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is that the same answer as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32009340/1048572)? If you think the question is a duplicate, please vote to close instead of copying answers.

Comment: They are very close to the same, but they both come up at the top of search results for similar questions.  In any case, I don't have that ability.  I think you need 3k rep for close/reopen votes.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue here but i solved it by adding **promise** and **resolve** the response without using **bluebird**, this is an exemple of my code :

```
async getLdapUser(username: any): Promise<any> {
    let myPromise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('ssssssssss', username);
      const adSuffix = 'OU=xxxx,OU=xxxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxx'; 
      const password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      // Create client and bind to AD
      const client = ldap.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://1.1.1.1:389',
      });
      // promise.promisifyAll(client);
      let resp = false;
      // console.log(client);
      client.bind('userTest', password,(err: any) => {
        console.log('RESP', resp);
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error in new connetion ' + err);
        } else {
          /*if connection is success then go for any operation*/
          console.log('Success');
          const searchOptions: {} = {
            scope: 'sub',
            filter: '(sAMAccountName=' + username + ')',
            attributes: ['sAMAccountName'],
          };

          client.search(adSuffix, searchOptions, (err: any, res: any) => {
            assert.ifError(err);
            res.on('searchEntry', (entry: any) => {
              resp = true;

            });
            res.on('error', (error: any) => {
              console.log('err');
              reject(error.message);
            });

            await res.on('end', (result: any) => {
              resolve(resp);

            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
    return myPromise;

  }
```